# how can I pass some nodes as init in sklearn.kmeans(n_clusters,init,....) in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means, adjacency-matrix, complex-networks

how can I pass 2 nodes as centroids to sklearn.kmeans(n_clusters,init,....)  instead of random or kmeans++?
algorithms['kmeans'] = KMeans(n_clusters=k_clusters,init='random', n_init=200)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sklearn` also allows users to input centroids of shape `(n_clusters, n_features)`.

The documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html

For less than `n_clusters`, you could use random initialization and pass it.

Comment: I know but I have a dataset called "zarchy karate club" which represents a graph. the points are not in space by default. There were some implementations of  kmeans clustering for it like the one on https://www.learndatasci.com/tutorials/k-means-clustering-algorithms-python-intro/, but I wonder how can I pass some nodes as centroids to sklearn.cluster.kmeans?! I dont know what (n_clusters, n_features) mean in this case?!

Comment: Then it is not that simple. You'd have to send them to a `networkx` plot function, get their location, then select centroids, pass that.

Comment: As for your `n_clusters, n_features` doubt, do consider reading a bit about kmeans -- atleast from the documentation I posted in my answer.

Comment: Can I use kmeans.transform for this purpose? Does it change data to change to locations?

Comment: Well technically, before you use `transform`, you need to `fit`. Else it uses untrained, random centroids.

Comment: Can you give me some examples of (n_clusters, n_features) especially for my dataset